# Binary search slower than hardcoded if branches from generated code?

Tags: java, c, clojure, jvm

[This guy](http://www.learningclojure.com/2010/09/clojure-faster-than-machine-code.html) makes the extraordinary claim that binary search (in a C compiler) is slower than hard-coded if-branches from generated code. 
(Please excuse the Clojure code and the wacky title - this claims this guy makes are related to compilers in general).

He writes

> I have seen this sort of code occasionally in dark corners.  When a man knows
>     how his processor works, knows how his C compiler works, knows his data
>     structures, and really, really needs his loops to be fast then he will
>     occasionally write this sort of thing.
>
> This is sort of code that Real Programmers write.

This is the binary search example (Please excuse the Clojure)

```
Start: (1 2 3 4 6 8 9 10 11 12)
Finish: ((((1) (2)) ((3) ((4) (6)))) (((8) (9)) ((10) ((11) (12)))))
```

Then he replaces a binary search with a generated code branched if based on hardcoded values:

```
(defn lookup-fn-handwritten [x]
  (if (< x 6) 
    (if (< x 3)                         ; x is < 6
      (if (< x 2)                       ; x is < 3
        (if ( < x 1)                    ; x is < 2
          0                             ; < 1
          1)                            ; 1 <= x < 2
        3)                              ; 2 <= x < 3
      (if (< x 4)                       ; 3 <= x < 6
        4                               ; 3 <= x < 4
        2))                             ; 4 <= x < 6
    (if (< x 10)                        ; 6 <= x < 10
      (if (< x 9)                       ; 6 <= x < 9
        (if (< x 8) 
          2                             ; 6 <= x < 8
          3)                            ; 8 <= x < 9
        3)                              ; 9 <= x < 10
      (if (< x 11)                      ; 10 < x
        (if (< x 12)                    ; 11 <= x
          1                             ; 11 <= x < 12
          0)
        0))))                           ; 12 <= x
```

http://www.learningclojure.com/2010/09/clojure-faster-than-machine-code.html

My question is - will a branched hardcoded if from generated code and hardcode values be more efficient than a binary search? (In any language - but the author claims this works in C - and then seems to only demonstrate it on the JVM).

(Please again excuse the wacky title of the linked post - that's just craziness.)

Comment: nothing wrong with his title, one could say that a good algorithm will always destroy a hand optimised assembler version of a bad algorithm any day.

Comment: It's not really an extraordinary claim...

Comment: For a set this small, an array lookup or a switch statement will be faster and its `O(1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the if-cascade probably does the same thing as the binary search, which means that it does the same comparisons, but without the associated "binary search management". It's an unrolled loop, and there is indeed a reason why compilers unroll loops. So yes, it will be faster.

But will it REALLY be faster? Now there's a problem called "cache". Whether you unroll a loop or anything else, your code gets larger, so the benefit might be offset by more memory accesses to run the code.

In addition, you never quite know what kind of instructions the compiler might be using to optimize the code, which it might not be using when you manually unroll the loop. Or the other way 'round, who knows. Even more so in languages that have a binary search "built in" so the compiler knows what it is dealing with.

Thus, just counting operations like "I have all the compares and none of the other stuff" may not be enough; there are other factors that affect execution time. And if you profile on one CPU to find out "my unrolled version is faster", another CPU might still disagree.

Optimizing is a b-word, not sure whether I'm allowed to spell it out here :-)

Comment: You're largely right except for the opening quote "When a man knows how his processor works...." - which basically changes the emphasis of the question as you will know the CPU, the Compiler, the cache sizes, the relative bus latency, bandwidth etc.. I have worked with very clever dedicated developers who could gain significant performance by really understanding all of the above - which to my reading was the essence of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The "hard-coded" version is also a binary search, just written much more efficiently than most binary search implementations. I don't see the claim as extraordinary at all. You may, however, be able to make a general binary search comparably fast if you avoid most of the typical implementation inefficiencies.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of comparison can be very difficult on modern JVMs.
 **because the HotSpot compiler makes many dynamic optimizations at runtime** if it detects that a class is running many times it will start extensively **inlining the function calls**, which results in a tree of nested if expressions.

When doing this sort of comparison it is important to "warm up" the JVM on that class a few million times to let this sort of inlining finish. I would not expect the difference to be very pronounced.

Answer (score 1):

The cascading if is effectively a specific binary search so you save by not having the code to implement a generic binary search, effectively it's an [unwound loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) so it's always going to be faster.

In a generic situation (i.e. where you're not targeting a specific configuration) you may well find that the CPU cache compromises unrolled loop performance once the loop is too big for the cache.

First rule of optimisation is to measure, find the problems and optimise accordingly and the original link is an excellent example of this that fits a specific configuration.

So yes, a good algorithm will always beat a bad algorithm pretty much regardless of the compiler, interpreter or CPU. That's the point being made in the original link.

[image: Algorithm efficiency]